# Select rows from Spark DataFrame based on a condition

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, top-n

I have two Spark dataframes:

```
df1
+---+----+
| id| var|  
+---+----+
|323| [a]|
+---+----+

df2
+----+----------+----------+
| src| str_value| num_value| 
+----+----------+----------+
| [a]|     ghn12|      0.0 |
+----+----------+----------+
| [a]|     54fdg|      1.2 |
+----+----------+----------+
| [a]|     90okl|      0.7 |
+----+----------+----------+
| [b]|     jh456|      0.5 |
+----+----------+----------+
| [a]|     ghn12|      0.2 |
+----+----------+----------+
| [c]|     ghn12|      0.7 |
+----+----------+----------+
```

I need to return top 3 rows from `df2` dataframe where `df1.var == df2.src` and `df2.num_value` has the smallest value. So, desired output is (sorted by `num_value`):

```
+----+----------+----------+
| src| str_value| num_value| 
+----+----------+----------+
| [a]|     ghn12|      0.0 |
+----+----------+----------+
| [a]|     ghn12|      0.2 |
+----+----------+----------+
| [a]|     90okl|      0.7 |
+----+----------+----------+
```

I know how to implement this using SQL, but I have some difficulties with PySpark/Spark SQL.

Comment: Are ```df1.var``` and ```df2.src``` columns of ArrayType()?

Comment: Yes, `df1.var` and `df2.src` are `array` type with `element:double`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it using [`dense_rank`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank.html#pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank) window function.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

w = W.partitionBy('src').orderBy('num_value')
df3 = (
    df2
    .join(df1, df2.src == df1.var, 'semi')
    .withColumn('_rank', F.dense_rank().over(w))
    .filter('_rank <= 3')
    .drop('_rank')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, col

windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("src").orderBy("num_value")

df_joined = df1.join(df2,df1.var==df2.src).drop("var", "id")
df_joined.withColumn("row_number",row_number().over(windowSpec)).filter(col("row_number")<4).drop("row_number").show()

# +---+---------+---------+
# |src|str_value|num_value|
# +---+---------+---------+
# |[a]|    ghn12|      0.0|
# |[a]|    ghn12|      0.2|
# |[a]|    90okl|      0.7|
# +---+---------+---------+
```